# devEMF export and powerpoint issue

Tags: r, plot, powerpoint

Had some recent issues with my workflow.  I normally print Rplots as .emf files using the devEMF package, and then edit them in powerpoint. [Import the emf file to powerpoint, right click on image, and select ungroup.] However, recently powerpoint isn't recognizing the vector format when I "ungroup."

I'm using a windows machine and powerpoint 2016.

Any thoughts would be VERY helpful. 
Nate

Comment: Well, I answered my own question: I loaded previous version of devEMF and all is well with the world. I'll report back if I get any further info: 

require(devtools)
install_version("devEMF", version = "2.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

Answer (score 2):

Just to leave a definitive answer here -- Powerpoint does not yet allow editing ("ungrouping") of EMF+ graphics.  Thus the solution is to tell devEMF to not use emfPlus features (the downside being that features such as transparency will not be available):

```
emf(file = "test.emf", emfPlus = FALSE)
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

The original poster's comment worked because the older version of devEMF did not use emfPlus by default.