# How do I resize charts created in R and paste in powerpoint while still keeping the figures sharp and readable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, powerpoint

I'm creating a presentation in powerpoint and need to copy and paste some charts created in R to the presentation. While I do know I can create presentations using rmarkdown, I need to use really small text and paste multiple charts side by side along with multiple tables to fit into a 5 page presentation and I'm not really sure how to do so using rmarkdown, so I'm creating the presentation manually. However when I reside charts from R in the powerpoint, they loose the sharpness and get blurry. See example below -

[image]

Is there a way to resize my charts from R and paste manually in a powerpoint, while still keeping the photos sharp. See reproducible code below -

```
data <- mutate(mtcars, car.name = row.names(mtcars))
data %>% 
    slice(1:20) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(mpg, car.name))+
    geom_col()+
    geom_text(aes(label = mpg))+
    theme_bw()+
    labs(title = "MPG by Car Brand", x = "", y = "")+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242662/devemf-export-and-powerpoint-issue

Comment: `ggsave` with `width` and `height`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set a directory using

```
setwd()
```

then you could use just "ggsave()", and set both height and width

```
ggsave("My_plot.jpg", My_Plot, width = 4, height = 6 )
```

The plot should be saved at the directory you just defined. You could also just paste the whole direction when defining the file's name.